# Android "Global Variables" Not Persisting

Tags: java, android, string, persistence

I have created a class that extends Application to store variables I want to access from multiple activities

```
public class MyApplication extends Application 
{
private String fbId, firstName;
private long expires;

@Override
public void onCreate() 
{
    super.onCreate();
}

public String getFbId() 
{
    return fbId;
}

public void setFbId(String fbId) 
{
    this.fbId = fbId;
}

public String getFirstName()
{
    return firstName;
}

public void setFirstName(String firstName) 
{
    this.firstName = firstName;
}
```

I am able to access these variables and set these variables the first time I am running the app. Once I quit out and restart the application it sets my values to null, any suggestions for why this may be happening?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you don't store your data in storage (that doesn't need to be a database, could be a flat file, SharedPreferences, or whatever) then it is not persistent.

You should be using [**`SharedPreferences`**](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#pref) to save this kind of persistent data.

> The SharedPreferences class provides a general framework that allows you to save and retrieve persistent key-value pairs of primitive data types. You can use SharedPreferences to save any primitive data: booleans, floats, ints, longs, and strings. This data will persist across user sessions (even if your application is killed).

Comment: This is the right answer, nothing in RAM is, by definition, persistent.

Comment: Ok, I had been using SharedPreferences before, but I thought this would work similarly.

Comment: If you don't store your data in storage (that doesn't need to be a database, could be a flat file, SharedPreferences, or whatever) then it is not persistent.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to persist a variable in any language. As long as the Program's life cycle is over all the variables gets destroy, and Memory get released from RAM/Heap Memory.

For persistence You have following options,

1. **File System**

   - A Simple File Format ( e.g. .txt )
   - Comma Separated File Format ( e.g. .csv )
2. **Database**

   - Sqlite ( in case of Android )
   - RMS ( in case of Java ME, BlackBerry )
3. **Programming Languag's supported Persistence Storage**

   - SharredPreference

Only by storing your variable's value into any of above mechanism you can make your values **persistence**.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to persist the data if you need them when you come back. You can use different storage medium for the same like, SharedPreference, Local Files, sqlite etc. Please refer [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html)